# SVG images for JavaFX-based game client

Tags: vector, svg, games

A group of programmers and designers are making a Trading Card Game (TCG). I work mostly on creative material. The Java game client is using JavaFX for GUI and we are looking to use primarily vector-based images, as the art for the TCG will be mostly comic book style.

We are looking to select a file type that is compatible with JavaFX and Adobe Creative Suite (primarily Illustrator). Concerns are in part storage size within the application, and scalability across platforms, including HTML-based websites. Would SVG be a good choice? Why, or why not?

Here is a screenshot of the SVG options we have available through Adobe Suite:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG would be an excellent cross-platform, cross-medium vector-based art file format. But I wouldn't recommend using Illustrator's default SVG exports as they tend to come cluttered with unneccessary metadata and often are quite un-optimized. Instead, save your source artwork as native AI file formats (in case you need to go back and re-edit), and then export SVG's from these files and then run those SVG's through SVGO (https://github.com/svg/svgo) to optimize them to the best extent possible. If you want a GUI for SVGO, try https://github.com/jakearchibald/svgomg which provides a web application GUI around the SVGO code.